# OutOfMemory-Exception - decodeBitmap()

Tags: android, camera, out-of-memory, onactivityresult

In my app I am starting a camera intent to take a picture with the standard camera app. I am saving the uri of the path of the image, and in onActivityResult() I am getting the bitmap with following code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);

    File dest = new File(uri.getPath());
    FileInputStream fis;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(dest);
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ...
```

My problem is that I am getting an outofMemoryException on one of my older phones, butinterestingly not with .decodeStream(), but when I am inflating a view in the fragment I am calling to display the bitmap:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment_image, container, true);
```

I read that decodeStream() is not very efficient and takes up a lot of memory. Using a content resolver seems to not be working with some Samsung devices.

So what can I do to prevent the outOfMemory-Exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This Code:- 

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         options.inDither = false;
         options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
         options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
         options.inSampleSize = 1;
         options.inPurgeable = true;
         options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
         options.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
 Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis,options);


and manifest file in this code use:-

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"                   //This line add in application tag
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the image to smaller size to prevent Out Of Memory error using:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 2;
if (height >= reqHeight || width >= reqWidth) {
    inSampleSize *= 2;
}
return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String file,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
        reqHeight);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but why are you decoding the bitmap, then setting the sampleSize, and then decoding the bitmap again, this time returning the bitmap?